# how to delete some data from hdfs file in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'd uploaded **50GB** data on Hadoop cluster. **But Now i want to delete first row of data file.**
This is time consuming if i remove that data & change manually. Then upload it again on HDFS.
Please reply me.

Answer (score 3):

HDFS files are immutable ([for all practical purposes](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/07/file-appends-in-hdfs/)).

You need to upload the modified file(s). You can do the change programatically with a M/R job that does a near-identity transformation, eg. running a [streaming](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming) shell script that does [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), but the gist of it that you need to create *new* files, HDFS files cannot be edited.

Comment: Thank you Remus. Can we edit HDFS files with any tool. like HBase